# GhostMethods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

Is there a possibility to implement rubylike ghost methods in Javascript?

The word ghost method means a method that doesn't really exist. If you call object.ghostMethod(), the Method isn't actually declared. There is a function called "method_missing()" in Ruby, which reacts to invocations to methods which aren't declared for the object.

Does a method similar to "method_missing()" exist in Javascript or is it possible to intercept all calls to a object?

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779624/does-javascript-have-something-like-rubys-method-missing-feature

Comment: Thx, didn't find it with the used Keywords.

Comment: See my answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3858415/1541563

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
if (typeof(ghost.method) != "undefined") {
    //method exists
}
```